# Next 13, Contentful - How to fix Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken?

Tags: next.js, contentful, next.js13, .env

Im using Next 13 and Contentful as my cms, I'm trying to define const client and export it So that I won't have to define it in every other backend file.

example
contentful.js

```
import { createClient } from "contentful";

// Create the Contentful client
export const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});
```

.env

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=somevalue
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=somevalue
```

logos.js

```
import { client } from "./contentful";
import { cache } from "react";

export const revalidate = 3600;

export const getLogos = cache(async () => {
  const response = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "partner",
  });

  return response.items;
});
```

And I get this error, but when I define the client in the logos.js file it works perfectly.
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken

Source
lib\contentful.js (4:35) @ eval

```
2 | 
  3 | // Create the Contentful client
> 4 | export const client = createClient({
    |                                 ^
  5 | space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  6 | accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  7 | });
```

Comment: Hey, can you let me know what routing you are using? I tried with my example that uses the pages route, and this is working as expected.